# In UML should we declare classes as abstract if they serve as a base class?

Tags: class, object, polymorphism, uml, abstract

We are having a UML course. The teacher said:

> Every class should be declared as abstract if it serves as base class for
>   its derived classes.

In the following figure suppose that we want to derive `class german shepherd` and `class labrador` from `class chien (Dog woof woof)`. Is it an obligation for `class chien` to become an **abstract class** or not?

[image]

Comment: If your base class does not specify a well defined behavior an interface can be used instead of an abstract class. I suppose that  the sentence mentioned by your teacher is too stringent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not necessarily.

That statement isn't necessarily true. A more correct statement would be:

> Every class should be declared as abstract if it cannot be instantiated without referring to a concrete derived class.

In your example, it makes sense that `Dog` and `Animal` would be abstract, because you have more specific classes that likely fill out details that the base classes do not.

However, it is certainly possible to have a class which is concrete and can be instantiated, (and therefore not abstract), but still serve as the base for another class.

Comment: Also, making a generalization set {complete} is even stronger. It means that there can be no instance of the superclass without that instance also being an instance of at least one of the subclasses.

Comment: @JimL., your suggestion only makes sense if there are multiple (explicitly named) generalization sets under the same superclass, which is a rare case. Making the superclass abstract is equally strong as having one {complete} generalization set containing all subclasses (if the superclass is abstract, there can be no instance of the superclass without that instance also being an instance of at least one of the subclasses).

Answer (score 1):

It should be abstract if it's a generalization and cannot exist on it's own.
Look at this situation:
[image]

In the image above Relation is abstract. It can't exist by it's own. Customer and Employee are normal classes who extend Relation. But Trainee is a Employee.
You could create a Employee, but also a trainee which is a Employee as well.